# Blender 2.80 and 2.83 do not work (a black screen and very slow)

Tags: gpu

Dears!

My system is:

```
koluna@lev:~$ inxi -F
System:    Host: lev Kernel: 5.4.0-54-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: M5A78L-M PLUS/USB3 v: Rev X.0x serial: <superuser/root required> 
           BIOS: American Megatrends v: 0502 date: 11/18/2016 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: AMD FX-6300 bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           Speed: 1405 MHz min/max: 1400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1406 2: 1404 3: 1406 4: 1400 5: 1405 6: 1405 
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000] driver: radeon v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RS780 (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-54-generic LLVM 10.0.0) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 
Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon 3000/3100 / HD 3200/3300] driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-54-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 04:92:26:c3:9e:0b 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 104.13 GiB (11.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: HDWD110 size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 91.17 GiB used: 13.33 GiB (14.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: /home size: 820.47 GiB used: 90.80 GiB (11.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 3.81 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 25.4 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 240 Uptime: 1h 43m Memory: 7.51 GiB used: 2.66 GiB (35.4%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

I use Blender 2.80 from an official site.
When I run it, it fails!
I tried to run it with CLI and I got some errors (see bellow).
When Blender was started OS works very slowly and I have a periodically black screen (a normal image is changed with a black screen).

```
~/soft/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64$ ./blender
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   170
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Warning: Could not find a matching GPU name. Things may not behave as expected.
Detected OpenGL configuration:
Vendor: X.Org
Renderer: AMD RS780 (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-54-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 153
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
found bundled python: /home/koluna/soft/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.80/python
Terminated
```

What is wrong?
Is my MB's graphic adapter a very old and a very bad?
What can I do?
I have tried another version (Blender 2.83). It was run, but works very slowly and has the same problems with screen.

Comment: Hello :). Your GPU is too old to be supported by Blender 2.8. No worries, you can still download some older Blender version https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/

Comment: The previous versions have many differencies :(
I started my learning since 2.80. And I want to use at least 2.80.
Can I use an external card? What will you advise to me? Maybe I will buy not expensive card that compliant with Blender 2.80+, my PC and my OS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on hardware :). But you can check [Blender minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)

Comment: 2.80 does not work. **2.82 works.** 2.83 does not work. 2.91 does not work. I have another PC (Athlon 200GE with integrated card and Mint 19.3) and Blender 2.80 works fine!!!

Comment: What is the difference between 2.80 and 2.82? 2.82 and 2.83? I mean the grapic algorithms.

Comment: Hello :). The difference is minimal, almost nonexistent. Use 2.82

Comment: And why does 2.80 not work? :)

Comment: Hey :). No idea, sorry. I don't use Blender on linux, so you'd need to ask someone else. If 2.82 works, I'd use it, it's a bit more 'polished' than 2.8.